# Relative positioning with z-index

Tags: css, html, click, z-index

I have 2 divs. Second is under first.

[image]

2nd div has `z-index: -1; top: -20px; position: relative`. Now I want to put some links(a-tag) into 2nd div: `<a href="#">test</a>`. Now I see my link but it's inactive. I can't click at it. When I remove `z-index: -1` it works. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative z-index can behave buggy. I would give the top div a higher z-index. You can better have something like this:

```
div.1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
div.2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px
}
```

You're links should be clickable, if they are visible of course.